# Is there any good reference for Second order Elliptic PDE other than Gilberg Trudinger?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I had done a course in PDE. I wanted to learn Elliptic PDE on my own. My teacher suggested me book Gilberg Trudinger. I am reading that. It is a good book. I am understanding almost all calculation. But I do not understand why Auther doing such steps. What is motivation? The book is full of estimate everywhere with different norms.

Please can anyone suggest me some good book with enough motivation to understand Elliptic PDE that would be very nice.

Any Help will be appreciated. Than

Comment: Any decent book in PDE's treats elliptic ones, harmonic equations, Laplacians and stuff. Maybe a book designed for physicists and/or engineers would give a good ammount of motivation, background and etc.

Comment: [Related Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534216/book-searching-in-elliptic-equation).

Comment: Evans, and Folland